# How to SUM of rows on Condition in next column using SELECT

Tags: mysql, select, sum

I have a dataset/table structure like below

```
|Dept|Rate|No.Of Employee |
|----|----|---------------|
| A  | 8  |      2        |
| A  | 5  |      2        | 
| B  | 10 |      2        | 
| B  | 5  |      2        |
```

Expecting the output of the SELECT / SQL to be

```
|Dept|Rate|No.Of Employee |  TotalHoursPerWeek  | TotalCostPerWeek   |TotalCostPerEmplPerDept |
|----|----|---------------|---------------------|--------------------|------------------------|
| A  | 8  |      2        |         80          |          640       |        1040            |
| A  | 5  |      2        |         80          |          400       |        1040            |
| B  | 10 |      2        |         80          |          800       |        1200            |
| B  | 5  |      2        |         80          |          400       |        1200            |
```

I have tried below `SELECT`, however not able to SUM 'TotalTotalCostPerWeek' based on 'Dept' & 'Employee'

Please note `SUM(TotalCostPerWeek 'per' Dept)` in below query is more for representation purpose, as I know/understand it will not work in SQL, hence need help/suggestion on how to get this kind of result using `SELECT` statement.

```sql
SELECT Dept, Rate, NoOfEmployee, 
      (NoOfEmployee * 40) AS TotalHoursPerWeek, 
      (NoOfEmployee *  40* Rate) AS TotalCostPerWeek, 
      SUM(TotalCostPerWeek 'per' Dept) AS TotalCostPerEmplPerDept
 FROM TABLE
 GROUP BY Dept, Rate;
```

Comment: Hey man. Your question is a little bit hazy. Can you add the schema tables and clarify your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you need and you can use "case when" to achieve this...

```
Select Dept,
       Rate,
       No_of_employee,
       TotalHoursPerWeek = (No_of_employee * 40),
       TotalCostPerWeek = (No_of_employee * 40 * Rate)
       TotalCostPerEmplPerDep = case when Dept ='A' then (select SUM(No_of_employee * 40 * Rate) from table where Dept = 'A')
                                 else (select SUM(No_of_employee * 40 * Rate) from table where Dept <> 'A')    
from table
```

Comment: What-IF, the 'Dept' needs to be dynamic value? I mean the table would have many such dept, so how can we put a specific 'dept' in WHEN and also WHERE. As we loop thru the rows, the SELECT should calculate the SUM dynamically as 'Dept' changes from one row to another.

Comment: Then try TotalCostPerEmplPerDep = (select SUM(No_of_employee * 40 * Rate) from table t2 where t1.Dept = t2.Dept group by Dept)

Answer (score 0):

You have only aggregation function for Dept, while the othersc olumn don't need  aggregation
in this case you shoudl use a join on a subquery for aggregated  result

```
SELECT Dept, rate, NoOfEmployee, 
      (NoOfEmployee * 40) AS TotalHoursPerWeek, 
      (NoOfEmployee *  40 * Rate) AS TotalCostPerWeek
from TABLE 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Dep,  SUM(ToOfEmployee *  40 * Rate) AS TotalCostPerEmplPerDept
    FROM TABLE
    GROUP BY Dept
) t on t.Dept = TABLE.Dept
```